# How to design XML Restful service interface for file uploading?

Tags: web-services, model-view-controller, rest, architecture

We have some XML restful services implemented in MVC (C#). Their overall look and feel is very similar to http://www.zendesk.com/api.

Now we need to accept some files uploaded.

The services are intended for consumption from PHP / Python / ruby and other popular web development languages.

How should we do it right? multipart/form-data? or just read post body?

I'm concerned about the ease of use from mentioned languages and popular web development frameworks. Unfortunately, i don't have anyone to ask on consumer side.

I'm also concerned about memory consumption. As i understand, multipart/form-data will be converted by MVC / ASP.NET to HttpPostedFileClass which caches itself on the web server disk. But plain POST won't, so it will consume IIS memory?

Maybe there are other notable options to consider? What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a very standard content management application, which REST excels at.

The most straightforward way would be to PUT to a resource whose name is a single file, say http://www.example.com/myfileserver/folder1/folder2/myfile  Then you GET the same resource to download the file, PUT to update the file, and DELETE to get rid of it.

In REST, the HTTP operation verb is crucial: POST is designed to add a new resource to the server when you *don't* know the resource name and the server assigns it. In your case you use PUT, which creates or updates a resource for which the name is known beforehand.

Comment: well, that's the simplest decicion. And what if i need to transfer some metadata with the file (excluding name/path)?